# Strange error in xcode after update to 4.5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am running an app of mine in xcode. It seems to work fine when I simulate it on the computer, but when I try to test it on my device, I get the error below. I've looked around for it but don't really know where to start as its a bit baffling! Has anyone seen this error or know even what it is in relation to?
Thanks.

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The secret is *typically* found in that linker warning seen in the image in your OP -- it likely says (paraphrased) "Ignoring image/file `PATH/TO/FILE` which does not have a matching architecture for the binary you are linking". When it finishes linking, it realizes that it's missing those symbols and emits the error.

Typically, this occurs when you have a library you link to which does not have matching `ARCHS` flags specified. Since Xcode 4.5 dropped armv6 and added support for armv7s, you may get different values depending on the toolchains you used to build the libraries.

The way around it is to open the project which compiles those symbols, and update its `ARCHS` to match your project's `ARCHS`.

Comment: And, in fact, the error message shown says, "undefined symbols for architecture armv7s" right there at the top...

Answer (score 2):

What is the deployment target set to? I bet it's lower than iOS 6, in which UICollectionView didn't exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try Targets -> Build Settings -> Build Active Architecture -> YES